# Is there a way to make Android open the emoji keyboard?

Tags: android, emoji

I was thinking if there is a way to open up the android keyboard or any other keyboard in the Emoji mode?

Below code is not required. This helps to open keyboard. I want to direct open emoji's keyboard.
    `android:inputType="textShortMessage|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"`